# "Ma'am" or "Miss" in American English?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, honorifics

Is it common to address a female sales clerk as Miss in the US?
What about ma'am?

If neither is proper, what would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest asking questions like this one at [ell.se], where they would be a better fit. Perhaps a moderator can migrate this.

Comment: @J.R. This would seem an especially interesting topic to discuss on this site. I would be particularly interested as to how modern America is changing in this regard and how the experience there compares and contrasts with how similar forms are used in Britain, both now and hitherto. The matter is at the very centre of where language interacts with social change.

Comment: @WS2: If the question asked about how America is trending, and how that trend compares with forms used in other parts of the English-speaking world (let's not leave the Aussies or New Zealanders out of this), that might be a good ELU topic. As written, though, it seems more of a simple yes-or-no query: "Yes, it would be polite and proper to call a US saleslady 'ma'am'." If such a confirmation is more what the O.P. is after, then ELL might be the better place to ask. More and more, I think it's not the question itself that best determines its home, but the depth of the answer being sought.

Comment: I think *ma'am* would be prefereable to *miss*.  But I have no official reference, so do not post an answer.

Comment: @J.R. I find it interesting, since in my lifetime, I cannot ever remember anyone calling a salesperson Sir or Madam (presumably the British equivalent of 'ma'am'). It certainly happens the other way around, and sales people make liberal use of both Sir and Madam for customers. But calling a lady 'Miss' would almost invite a slap in the face for misogyny.

Comment: When I was at school in the fifties we called any female teacher 'ma'am' irrespective of whether she was married. Though in some schools they used 'Miss' for unmarried teachers. My grandson calls his teacher Ms. But the idea of going into a supermarket and calling out 'miss' to one of the staff is enough to induce side-splitting laughter. The Queen likes to be called 'Ma'am' which rhymes with 'ham', and not 'marm' which rhymes with farm, if that is of any help!

Comment: @WS2 Your statement about farms makes no sense to most English speakers. You must be non-rhotic. I can tell you mean not to her Mom, but most people will not.

Comment: @tchrist I don't understand you. But a lot of people say ma'am to the Queen, in a way that rhymes with the way a non-rhotic person would say 'farm'. Apparently she hates this. If you saw the film 'the Queen', played by Helen Mirren, this matter was dealt with when Tony and Cherie Blair were presented to her for the first time, on his having won the 1997 election. 'You must say 'ma'am' which rhymes with ham.' I have no idea how rhotic people like those from South West England, Ireland or North America are advised. It is an interesting point.

Comment: @WS2 I would hate being called *Mom*, too: hard to blame her, really.  Why do people do that?  *Tom*, on the other hand, is just fine. Not sure what I think about *ham*. Perhaps if she told them it rhymes with *damn*, the stronger term would stick better in people’s memories, if not their craws.

Comment: @tchrist It is not 'Mom'. What she hates is 'farm' the way I say it - which is not the way you say it.

Comment: @WS2: RE: _I find it interesting, since in my lifetime, I cannot ever remember anyone calling a salesperson Sir or Madam..._ So, what **would** you call a salesperson, if you didn't know their name?

Comment: @J.R. Probably nothing at all. Nowadays most of them wear these little tags with their names on, but I think it would be unusual for a customer in a shop to address a sales person as anything, unless they knew them, and then they would use the name. If I wanted to attract the attention of a staff member in a supermarket to ask them where the sugar puffs were, I would just say 'Excuse me, please could you direct me to the sugar puffs'. Calling out 'miss' just sounds ridiculous. This is not just a modern trait, in my recollection it has always been like this. C.Fwd.

Comment: @J.R. In France, where once one might have called a waitress or a girl in a shop 'mademoiselle', it is now almost 'de rigueur' to say 'madame', unless the girl in question is quite clearly a child. Every English-French dictionary will tell you that the word for 'waiter'is 'garcon' (boy). but in half a century of visiting France, and living there for a time, I have never heard anyone call a waiter 'garcon'

Comment: @WS2 Next time I am in visit to the UK, I will purposely address the lady shop assistant with "Miss" and closely observe her body mannerisms and listen to her tone of voice. I think if someone were to ask: "Excuse me, Miss, where can I find....?" I would be very surprised if that lady reacted rudely or took offence. In my part of Italy, *signorina*, if she is obviously younger than me —a fact which is happening with alarming frequency — is perfectly fine. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA If the customer were clearly not a local person, but American or European, such as your good self, and it were somewhere like Harrods or Selfridges in London, you would likely get no reaction at all. Staff would be perfectly used to hearing it. But if you were in Tesco in Reading, or anywhere outside of central London or the main tourist places, it would be taken as very odd by a shop assistant to be called 'miss', or 'ma'am'. And I was perhaps wrong in ascribing it to feminism. It would have more to do with embarrassment at such formality, and was never any different years ago.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Would you call an adult woman 'signorina' in a shop in provincial Italy?

Comment: @WS2 *Signorina* if she were or even looked younger than 40-odd, then yes, I would. Otherwise, it would be a *"Mi scusi"* (Sorry...). I have never addressed any British woman by "ma'am", and I strongly dislike saying "Ms" but only because I'm not used to it. I think it's more of a late '90s thing.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss#Use_as_a_title_.28honorific.29) offers the following:

> The usage of "Miss" as a title in the United States is most frequently seen when referring to girls under eighteen. Though "Miss" is less commonly used as a title by unmarried adult women in the United States than in the past, some still prefer to be referred to as such. Twenty-first century etiquette honors an adult woman's personal preference of title. However, if the preference is not known, "[Miss]" is used. "[Miss]" is becoming the preferred choice as this female title in business. It is the equivalent to the male title "Mr." as neither is marital status specific.

Basically, the choice between these two honorifics has historically drawn from a woman’s age and marital status, but if you’re not sure you should probably use “Miss”.

---

<sup>On a personal note, I learned from *working* as a sales clerk that women with non-white hair almost universally prefer “Miss”. Sometimes it does not convey respect to imply that someone has earned it with their oldness.</sup>

Comment: "Ms." is not something you'd call a salesclerk though but would use in written correspondence.  "Miss" for younger women and "Ma'am" for older women is customary in my era and part of the world (U.S. Midwest)

Comment: The question is how to address the female shop assistant, not the client. But I'd say *Miss* is probably the best option, the least likely to offend or cause embarrassment.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I edited the post to clarify that "Ms." = "Miss".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your comment is phrased as a correction, but does not contradict anything in my post.

Comment: `Is it common to address a female sales clerk as Miss in the US? What about ma'am?` Your referenced answer doesn't really answer this point, it's a bit nebulous. Sorry. The small print should be less timid.

Answer (score 2):

*Miss* is both common and proper.  *Ma'am* is proper but not common.  *Ma'am* has connotations of both older and higher status, *Miss* connotes younger and lower status.  Since the sales-clerk is in a lower-status position *vis-a-vis* the customer, *Miss* is typical even when the clerk is older than the customer.  Conversely, the clerk might address the customer as *Ma'am*.  *Miss* is generally safe, because most people like to be thought of as young, even though it connotes a lower status.

Comment: I'm one of those "uncommon" habitual users of "Ma'am". As this answer hints at, I use it to show respect. Saying "Miss" is in effect saying "Hey, subservient female". Ugh. However, as this answer also gets at, Ma'am can get you into trouble. It can also imply that you perceive yourself to be younger than the woman in question. Some women can be really sensitive about their age. I've gotten a talking to over this in the past.

Comment: ...in fact, just last month I was reading a book where the protagonist went into a day long downward introspective spiral because some guy had called her "Ma'am"

Comment: It's quite regional; you'd likely hear _ma'am_ used a lot more in the some of the southern states. I've pointed to [this beer commercial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1YD8FLIPNM) before, and I'll do it again; it's hard to specify how "Americans" speak because people from Dallas don't always speak exactly like they do in New York, and those in Chicago don't necessarily greet each other in same way they do in Charleston. It's also cultural - those who grew up in career military families or served an enlistment might lean toward using "Sir" and "Ma'am" more often than the general population.

Comment: @T.E.D.  'Hey, subservient female' is exactly how calling a woman 'miss' would be seen in Britain and I suspect anywhere in Western Europe. Mademoiselle and fraulein are only used with children. It does seem astonishing that it should still be the practice in America, a country that has been in the vanguard of feminism, and where words like 'waitress' and 'bar-maid' are ruled out.

Comment: @WS2 - Don't be too astonished; I'm not so convinced that "_Miss_ is both common and proper," as this answer claims.

Comment: @J.R. But you very seldom hear anyone use 'sir' or 'madam' or ma'am' in Britain, except where the person concerned is a customer. Even then you would have to be in a fairly up-market establishment before you got called that. We are rather less formal than you are, you know. In the UK you are far more likely to get called 'darling' or 'sweetheart' by the check-out clerk than 'sir' or 'madam'!

Comment: @WS2 - Perhaps this just indicates what a bugaboo age is for women in our culture, that many women perversely consider it *more* respectful to be considered young than older. As for "darling" or "sweetheart", those can commonly be heard in the South in the USA. Anywhere else, it would be considered so disrespectful you'd be liable to get hurt.

Comment: A good workaround is "pardon me" or "excuse me" where no gender label is necessary.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Agreed, although I find those only work for getting someone's attention if you have already either touched them or established eye contact. Nobody answers to that.

Comment: @ws2 *waitress* is quite common in the US. quite. you don't see it as often on signs and whatnot anymore, and the title is often officially "server", but plenty of people still use the term *waitress*. *bar-maid* was never common in the states as far as i know of. it sounds like your memory's references are rather inaccurate. have you been to the us ?

Answer (score 2):

Growing up in a military family and serving myself, I'm not sure I would think to use the term "miss" when referring to a female I didn't know such as a clerk or waitress.  While I agree that "miss" generally connotes a younger woman, and "ma'am" an older woman, in the military (at least in my experience), it was always "ma'am", even to someone considerably younger than the speaker.  I may jokingly refer to one of my friend's children or my nieces as something like "young miss ", but those are girls that I know.

As pointed out by @JR, I was also raised with a southern mother, and it's definitely more common to hear "ma'am" in the southern states than others, so that was probably an influencer for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would be okay with the use of ma'am if were not consistently linked to age as we all know it is. I have seen some sales clerks call a woman perceived to be  younger miss and call the woman behind her ma'am. I see how this could bother some women because it is implying outright that the woman is older which may make some women feel bad because no one wants to be thought of as old, especially if they are younger, like ages 35-55. I feel if the word ma'am is to be used to address women that it should apply to all ladies, as sir applies to all men young and old. I also feel the word ma'am is misused. I mean there are people calling women ma'am that are clearly older than the woman.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a young adult and prefer "miss"; I've always thought of "ma'am as meant for women who are middle-aged or older. I actually made a survey on this topic, if anyone wants to take it: https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/S3W82WD

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. This answer is actually bordering on spam, as it redirects to a survey service. If you would like to post the _results_ of the survey, that would be fine.